# Are there any references for this theorem of Lercher?

Tags: reference-request, lambda-calculus

Let $\Delta = \lambda x.(x)x$ and consider $\Omega = (\Delta)\Delta$. Then $\Omega$ is exactly the only $\lambda$-term of the form $(\lambda x.t)v$ such that $(\lambda x.t)v=t\{v\ /\ x\}$.

Does someone have references about this statement ? I could not find something enough relevant in my ressources or in my lectures material.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I googled "lercher lambda-calculus" and found this: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-17/issue-2/Lambda-calculus-terms-that-reduce-to-themselves/10.1305/ndjfl/1093887539.full  Judging from the first few lines of the paper, it looks like it's what you're looking for, right?

Comment: @DamianoMazza Indeed that's it thank you !